# scalajs scrollIntoView with scrollIntoViewOptions

Tags: scala.js

[HTML scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) has two options: `scrollIntoView(alignToTop)` and `scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions)`, where scrollIntoViewOptions is an obbject with `behavior` ("auto" or "smooth"), `block` ("start", "center", "end", or "nearest") and `inline` ("start", "center", "end", or "nearest").

However, ScalaJs only imports the first option. Is there a raison for this?

---

I'd like to have this javacript code in scalajs:

```
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center"})
```

I've tried this scalajs code, but it does not work. It does not scroll at all. Any idea?

```
@js.native
trait ElementExtended extends Element {
    def scrollIntoView(o: scala.Dynamic): Unit = js.native
}
element.asInstanceOf[ElementExtended].scrollIntoView(js.Dynamic.literal(behavior = "smooth", block = "center"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this issue myself and solved it with the following:

```scala
@js.native
trait ElementExtras extends js.Object {
  def scrollIntoView(options: ScrollIntoViewOptions): Unit
}

trait ScrollIntoViewOptions extends js.Object {
  var behavior: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined
  var block: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined
  var inline: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined
}
```

I then added an implicit conversion to cast it:

```scala
implicit def element2Extras(element: html.Element): ElementExtras = element.asInstanceOf[ElementExtras]
```

Then, to use I just do the following:

```scala
element.scrollIntoView(new ScrollIntoViewOptions {
  behavior = "smooth"
  block = "end"
})
```